# static file are not loading in templates django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

i am very new to django .

m adding static files but they are not being shown in m templates when i runserver.

if i add an static image the image does not load but only shows a img icon.

```
#settings.py     
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
STATIC_DIR,
]

 #INDEX.HTML
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>hey eeyone</h1>
 <img src="{% static "images/hotel.jpg" %}">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a typo, it is [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) which is a list.

Comment: Thanks.it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to add static root in settings.py as - 
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
2. Then create a static folder in app.
3. In template load static as - 
   {% load static %}
4. Add stylesheets href as - 
   href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}"